# Why is Owl carousel not loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using an owl carousel for my project but it doesn't display images and no slideshow is taking place maybe I have missed something out I don't know but I have all JS and CSS files loaded correctly.

Here is a list of the files I'm using:

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slicknav.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">

<!-- MAIN CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooplate-style.css">

<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Then here is my carousel HTML code, the overlay class is just a black background helping with my navbar. I've included the jquery.js file because it helps with the scripts below it.

```html
<section id="home" class="hero-section">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="hero-slider owl-carousel">
    <div class="hs-item set-bg" data-setbg="images/4.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-7 text-white">
            <span>New Arrivals</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum sus-pendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </p>
            <a href="" class="site-btn sb-line">DISCOVER</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hs-item set-bg" data-setbg="images/2.jpg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-7 text-white">
            <span>New Arrivals</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum sus-pendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. </p>
            <a href="" class="site-btn sb-line">DISCOVER</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide-num-holder" id="snh-1"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Then my JavaScript code

```js
// BACKGROUND
$('.set-bg').each(function() {
  var bg = $(this).data('setbg');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
});

//CAROUSEL
var hero_s = $(".hero-slider");
hero_s.owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  margin: 0,
  nav: true,
  items: 1,
  dots: true,
  animateOut: 'fadeOut',
  animateIn: 'fadeIn',
  navText: ['<i class="flaticon-left-arrow-1"></i>', '<i class="flaticon-right-arrow-1"></i>'],
  smartSpeed: 1200,
  autoHeight: false,
  autoplay: true,
  onInitialized: function() {
    var a = this.items().length;
    $("#snh-1").html("<span>1</span><span>" + a + "</span>");
  }
}).on("changed.owl.carousel", function(a) {
  var b = --a.item.index, a = a.item.count;
  $("#snh-1").html("<span> " + (1 > b ? b + a : b > a ? b - a : b) + "</span><span>" + a + "</span>");
});

hero_s.append('<div class="slider-nav-warp"><div class="slider-nav"></div></div>');
$(".hero-slider .owl-nav, .hero-slider .owl-dots").appendTo('.slider-nav');
```

Please go through and correct me if I did a mistake somewhere. Thanks

I have set the background images using JavaScript to reduce on the load time but it's not working and I know I have two jQuery files included but the second one I think helps in loading the other scripts below it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your javascript files are included in the correct order

```
$('.set-bg').each(function() {
    var bg = $(this).data('setbg');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + bg + ')');
});

var hero_s = $(".hero-slider");
hero_s.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    nav: true,
    items: 1,
    dots: true,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    navText: ['<i class="flaticon-left-arrow-1"></i>', '<i class="flaticon-right-arrow-1"></i>'],
    smartSpeed: 1200,
    autoHeight: false,
    autoplay: true,
    onInitialized: function() {
        var a = this.items().length;
        $("#snh-1").html("<span>1</span><span>" + a + "</span>");
    }
})

hero_s.on("changed.owl.carousel", function(a) {
    var b = --a.item.index,
        a = a.item.count;
    $("#snh-1").html("<span> " + (1 > b ? b + a : b > a ? b - a : b) + "</span><span>" + a + "</span>");
});

hero_s.append('<div class="slider-nav-warp"><div class="slider-nav"></div></div>');
$(".hero-slider .owl-nav, .hero-slider .owl-dots").appendTo('.slider-nav');
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve it

Comment: Please have a look at this. 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html

Comment: Thanks that was really a helpful resource